# How to capture a macro's ultimate expansion as a string?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, catcodes

I have a macro `\a`. I'd like to define a macro `\b`, whose replacement text, `T`, will satisfy the following requirements:

1. The catcode of every token of `T` is in the range 10-12.
2. Ignoring catcodes, `T` is token-by-token equal to `\a`'s ultimate expansion.

For instance,

```
\def\z{12pt}%
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\z}\selectfont}%
\def\b{???}%
\b
```

should typeset:

> \noindent\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont

If this is not possible, it will be OK, too, if `\b` expands *everything* recursively, until there's nothing more to expand.

Finally, the following example, too, will be good enough:

```
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\a}\selectfont}%
\def\b{???}%
\b
```

should typeset:

> \noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\a}\selectfont

Comment: Please make a MWE.

Comment: "Ultimate expansion" -- at the time of definition (edef)? Or use (which is impossible)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: If possible, at the time of use.

Comment: @TeXnician: I've added a MWE.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: The latter. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: How does macro `\b` know that it should expand `\z` but not `\fontsize` and `\selectfont`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: If this is unreasonable to ask, than consider the second example I gave after that. It will be OK too if `\b` expands *everything* recursively until it can't anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without expansion of `\a` and with `\meaning`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\z{12pt}%
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\z}\selectfont}%
\makeatletter
\edef\b{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\a}
\makeatother
\texttt{\b}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The spaces after command names are inserted by TeX.

Variant with e-TeX's \detokenize:

```
\edef\b{\detokenize\expandafter{\a}}
```

In both cases, the tokens in the definition text of `\b` have category code 12 (other) and the space has category code 10 (space).

---

If the contents of `\a` is more or less known, then the macros that should not be expanded can be prevented from expansion by redefining them to the meaning of `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\z{12pt}%
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\z}\selectfont}%

\begingroup
  \let\fontsize\relax
  \let\selectfont\relax
  \edef\x{\a}
  \xdef\b{\detokenize\expandafter{\x}}
\endgroup
\texttt{\b}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A full expansion of `\a` only works for some macros with more or less useful result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\z{12pt}%
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\z}\selectfont}%

\edef\tmp{\a}
\edef\b{\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}}
\endgroup
\texttt{\b}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Adding package `microtype`, for example, will get a macro `\a` that breaks in a hard expansion by `\edef`:

```
! Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.7 \edef\tmp{\a}
```

LaTeX's protection mechanism can be used by the softer `\protected@edef`. Then, commands defined by `\DeclareRobustCommands` and commands with optional arguments are not expanded too much:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\def\z{12pt}%
\def\a{\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{\z}\selectfont}%

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\tmp{\a}
\makeatother
\edef\b{\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}}
\texttt{\b}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a version in which `\a` is expanded recursively until there's nothing left to expand?

Comment: @EvanAad First `\edef\a{\a}` and then `\edef\b{...}` from above.

Comment: The `\strip@prefix` is not very reliable, see the discussion in [Is there a reliable way to get the number of arguments of a command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305806/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-get-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-command).

Comment: By the way, will this also work when `\a`'s expansion is ill formed? I don't even know how to write it, but something along the lines of `\a\def{\macro{}`, where the replacement string has just an opening brace.

Comment: I meant `\def\a{\macro{}`.

Comment: @EvanAad And how do you want to define such a macro? `\def\a{\macro{}` will for sure raise an error.

Comment: @HenriMenke: As I said, I don't know exactly how to express this in TeX, but hopefully my meaning is clear: `\a`'s replacement text is an incomplete TeX expression. Like when you define a new environment: the beginning and end of the environment.

Comment: @EvanAad For unbalanced lists of tokens there is https://github.com/blefloch/latex-gtl

Comment: @HenriMenke `\def\a{\def\foobar{...}}` with `\foobar` previously undefined will break in an `\edef`, because `\def` is not executed and `\foobar` is undefined.