# How to use \numlist in combination with \uppercase

Tags: siunitx

In my project, at some point I need to use a `\numlist` from `siunitx` in an `\uppercase` environment. However, additional options to the numlist command are not detected properly, as can be seen in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This does work: \numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}.

\uppercase{This does not work: \numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}.}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following error

> The option file 'PARSE-NUMBERS' is not known by siunitx:perhaps it is
> spelled incorrectly.

and the resulting output is not correct.

Comment: This feels like an 'X-Y' question: could you give a bit more context?

Comment: I'm using the \numlist in a section title, which is capitalized when being used in the page heading. At that point, any option passed to \numlist is not working any longer (including the detect-all option to detect the font style)

Comment: Since the `\numlist` is not expandable, you will have to come up with a different approach, which will depend on the intended usage.  For example, `\sbox0{\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}}
\uppercase{This does not work: \box0.}` compiles, but "and" is not capitalized and the box will not respond to fontsize changes, etc.  Further, `\box0` is temporary and thus ephemeral.

Comment: It works if you use the `textcase` package and `\MakeTextUppercase{This does not work: \NoCaseChange{\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}}.}`

Comment: @daleif Sounds like an answer to me

Comment: Somewhat related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384911/how-to-capture-a-macros-ultimate-expansion-as-a-string

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously that `\uppercase` acts on the `key=val` pair.

One way around this is to use the `textcase` package and its `\MakeTextUppercase` and encase the stuff you do not want affected in `\NoCaseChange{...}`

This way this works

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\begin{document}

This does work: \numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}.

\MakeTextUppercase{This does not : \NoCaseChange{\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}}.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve your goal, but it means redefining `\sectionmark` each time you use `\numlist`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\csname protected@edef\endcsname\numlistA{\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{2;3;4;5X}}% \numlistA passed to TOC unexpanded
\tableofcontents

\csname protected@edef\endcsname\numlistB{\numlist[parse-numbers=false, list-final-separator={~AND~}]{2;3;4;5X}}%
\def\sectionmark#1{\let\numlistA\relax
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{#1}\numlistB}}

\section{This does not work \numlistA}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

What is really freaky is that if you change the definition of `\numlistA`, both the `\tableofcontents` and `\markright` will use the wrong definition with "AND" in the TOC and "and" in the header.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just use `\sisetup{list-final-separator = { AND }}`?

Comment: @JosephWright - It didn't occur to me. I was digging through the source code looking for something to patch.   I will use it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, however this does not work if the `\numlist` is used inside a `\section{}`, as in that case `and` needs to be formatted depending on whether it is for example in the table of contents or in a page heading.