# hide free text without additional environment

Tags: environments

to simplify let us say I have a document with only text and theorems.

I want to display only the text contained in theorems. For instance

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
blah
\section{Two}
\begin{theorem}
Blo
\end{theorem}
\chapter{Two}
Blih

\end{document}
```

I want only to have displayed:
**1.One**
1.One
2.Two
Theorem:Bloh"
**2.Two**

Is it possible without having to enclose the text in an additional environment?

One solution would be somehow to suppress the normal output with some trick, e.g. putting font size to 0 (didn't manage to do that), except in the theorems.

Thanks

EDIT: maybe one way to do it would be to automatically collect all the contents of theorems with some packages, not ouput the main document, and only output what has been collected, but I would also like to have chapter and section titles...

Comment: What documentclass and packages are you loading?  Please edit your question to provide a minimum working example.

Comment: There you go (I edited the post). I'm looking for something that works for different kinds of environments (not only theorems), and maybe for different kind of documentclass

Comment: I have revised and undeleted my prior solution.

Answer (score 1):

The OP stipulates "let us say I have a document with only text and theorems".

I use a `tokencycle` pseudo-environment named `\shothms...\endshothms`, one instance of which is wrapped around the whole document, to achieve the result.

As currently EDITED, it will only execute instances of `\chapter` & `\section` (without optional arguments) and `theorem` & `proposition` environments.  Note that optional arguments to these macros/environments can be dealt with via `tokcycle`, but I did not feel like investing the time and code here.  See [Parse Argument by Character while Executing Embedded Macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271607/parse-argument-by-character-while-executing-embedded-macros/561374#561374), for an example where it is done.

The macro tests (if one wanted to add additional macros to capture) is performed by the `\testmacros` macro

```
\newcommand\testmacros[1]{%
  \ifx\chapter#1\addcytoks{#1}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
  \ifx\section#1\addcytoks{#1}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
    \gdef\addarg{F}\fi\fi
}
```

The environment tests (if more are needed) are performed by the `\testenvs` macro, given as

```
\newcommand\testenvs[1]{%
  \ifx\thmchk#1 1\else
  \ifx\propchk#1 1\else
  0\fi\fi
}
```

given the preamble definitions

```
\def\thmchk{theorem}
\def\propchk{proposition}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\addarg{F}
\def\checktheorems{F}
\def\charson{F}
\def\thmchk{theorem}
\def\propchk{proposition}
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem{proposition}
\stripgroupingtrue
\tokcycleenvironment\shothms
  {\if T\charson\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  {%
    \if T\addarg\addcytoks{{##1}}\gdef\addarg{F}\fi
    \if F\checktheorems
      \if T\charson\addcytoks{{##1}}\fi
    \else
      \gdef\tmp{##1}%
      \ifnum\testenvs{\tmp}=1\relax
        \if B\checktheorems
          \addcytoks{\begin{##1}}\gdef\charson{T}%
        \else
          \addcytoks{\end{##1}}\gdef\charson{F}%
        \fi
      \fi%
    \fi
    \gdef\checktheorems{F}
  }
  {%
    \ifx\begin##1\gdef\checktheorems{B}\else
      \ifx\end##1\gdef\checktheorems{E}\else
        \gdef\checktheorems{F}%
        \if T\charson\addcytoks{##1}\fi%
      \fi
    \fi
    \testmacros{##1}%
  }
  {\if T\charson\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
\newcommand\testmacros[1]{%
  \ifx\chapter#1\addcytoks{#1}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
  \ifx\section#1\addcytoks{#1}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
    \gdef\addarg{F}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand\testenvs[1]{%
  \ifx\thmchk#1 1\else
  \ifx\propchk#1 1\else
  0\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
\shothms
\chapter{My Chapter}

Chapter text

\section{One}

blah blah
\section{Two}

\begin{theorem}
Bloh \textbf{Blah} \today
\end{theorem}

blih blih \textit{blow}

more blah

\begin{proposition}
Blah$^2$
\end{proposition}
Finis
\endshothms
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

If one wanted less formatting of the sectioning, one could redefine `\testmacros` as

```
\newcommand\testmacros[1]{%
  \ifx\chapter#1\addcytoks{\stepcounter{chapter}\par\noindent Chapter 
    \thechapter:~}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
  \ifx\section#1\addcytoks{\stepcounter{section}\par\noindent Section 
    \thesection:~}\gdef\addarg{T}\else
    \gdef\addarg{F}\fi\fi
}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, basically it rebuilds the whole document. I am looking for something more stable, that would work for instance with another documentclass, such as book with chapters, etc...I'm sorry I made only one MWE

Comment: @kaleidoscop This approach is perfectly stable.  The issue is that one has to inform it which macros to ignore and which to process.  As presented, it only processes `\section` and `theorem` environments.  Others could be added, with additional code

Comment: Ok, how would you proceed to include chapters and propositions?

Comment: @kaleidoscop Done.

Comment: @kaleidoscop I have provided what might be a useful **ADDENDUM** to my answer

Comment: Well, thanks! Unfortunately I ran it in my main document and it seems there are conflicts, I had a "runaway argument" error, with a "Paragraph ended before \tc@scapecytoks was complete". (and no erros before)..Maybe there are simpler solutions